# Show single value from multiple duplicate value

Tags: sql-server, plsql

I have a table in SQL Server, in this table I have a column `chq_no_start` with some duplicate cheque no, but the account id is different according those cheque no.

Now I want to show only one cheque no from those duplicate cheque no, no matter if one account id is missing.

I show my output:

[image: cheque duplicate]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
Select 
     distinct chq_no_start, 
     (select top 1 alt_acc_id from Table_name where chq_no_start= tn.chq_no_start order by alt_acc_id) Account_ID 
From 
     Table_name tn 
Order by 
     chq_no_start
```

Comment: This code working, I am slightly edit your code and its work for me.

Comment: You missed `order by` for `top`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DISTINCT keyword before the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
with cte as (
    select alt_acc_id, issue_date, no_of_chq, chq_no_start, 
      row_number() over (partition by chq_no_start order by alt_acc_id) RowNum
    from your_table
    where your_column = 'your_value')
select * from cte
where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Your code is ok but it will work when I give duplicate value, but i want to show the output that will contain only single value, duplicate cheque no show only single value, not multiple time.